# Internet Telephony(VoIP) in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to build android app for voice call without any sever. Presently i saw the sample app in android which uses SIP. But that needs a SIP Server. Can we do similar work without the need of any server. I am afraid that if i use any server then the load on the server will increase a lot with increase in number of user. Correct me if i am wrong. Any possible approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not possible since you just won't be able to identify and reach the user you want to call. The server is an interface between two or more users of your app. Increased load? Sure. Consider using a better server configuration when your number of users grows.

Comment: You have any idea whats the role of server apart from establishing the connection? Does server have any role after connection is established between source and destination.

Comment: as far as I know the server maintains the connection realtime and takes the overall control, e.g. re-establishing the connection in case any errors occurred etc.